# ArcMap Using Python to Rename a Feature Class based on Print Results

Tags: python, arcpy, fields-attributes, cursor, search

I would like to rename a feature class based on the EDITOR and DATE fields. I wrote this code:

```
    import arcpy

fc = "C:\Users\PythonTesting.gdb\MyFile"
f1, f2, f3 = "EDITOR", "DATE", "OBJECTID"
clause = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, f3) + "= 1"
for row in sorted (arcpy.da.SearchCursor (fc, [f1, f2], clause)):
     print ("{0}_{1}".format(row[0], row[1]))
```

And it works great, prints out the one line of results I want. But now I can't figure out how to use those results as the output for a rename. I have used the rename before but with out such an expression.

I checked out this one thinking it would help but I still can't figure it out.
[How to rename feature classes based on field values within the attribute table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14925/how-to-rename-feature-classes-based-on-field-values-within-the-attribute-table)

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. Boy that was easy!

```
>>> import arcpy
... 
... fc = "C:\Users\PythonTesting.gdb\My_File"
... f1, f2, f3 = "EDITOR", "COUNTY", "OBJECTID"
... clause = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, f3) + "= 1"
... for row in sorted (arcpy.da.SearchCursor (fc, [f1, f2], clause)):
...     print ("{0}_{1}".format(row[0], row[1]))
...     name =("{0}_{1}".format(row[0], row[1]))
...     arcpy.Rename_management(fc, name)
```

My major problem was the way the date is formatted. But knowing that this function works is good, now I just need to fix the date.